# UDP сервер с несколькими клиентами

Tags: c++, windows, winsock, udp

Добрый День. Разбираюсь с сокетами. Пишу простенький UDP сервер,по которому передаются сообщения. Все активные клиенты отправляют "keepalive" сообщения раз в три минуты , чтобы сервер видел, какие из клиентов онлайн.

Приём этих сообщений осуществляется в потоке

```
void keepAlive(SOCKET udp)
{
int len=0;
while(true)
{
 int len=recvfrom(udp,requestBuffer,maxMessage,0,(sockaddr*)&cliAddr,&cliAddrSize)
// тут действия с принятым сообщением
}
}
```

Но как реализовать, например, передачу сообщений всем клиентам или конкретному,если сокет уже "занят". Будет ли sendTO вне этого потока работать нужно создавать новый сокет? Вообще не трогать потоки?

Такой же вопрос и со стороны клиента (т.к. keepalive вынесен в поток, но при решении данной проблемы, другая решается тоже)